# How to fetch website links when they're not numerically ordered

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Using beautifulsoup it's easy to fetch URLs that follow a certain numeric order. However how do I fetch URL links when it's organized otherwise such as `https://mongolia.mid.ru/en_US/novosti` where it has articles like

`https://mongolia.mid.ru/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/24-avgusta-sostoalas-vstreca-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-s-ministrom-energetiki-mongolii-n-tavinbeh?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1`?

Websites such as these are weird because once you first open the link, you have `» Бусад мэдээ`  button to go to the next page of articles. But once you click there, now you have `Previous` or `Next` button which is so unorganized.

How do I fetch all the news articles from websites like these (`https://mongolia.mid.ru/en_US/novosti` or `https://mongolia.mid.ru/ru_RU/`)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `» Бусад мэдээ`  button from `https://mongolia.mid.ru/ru_RU/` just redirects to `https://mongolia.mid.ru/en_US/novosti`. So why not start from the latter?

To scrape all the news just go page through page using the link from the `Next` button.
If you want it to be more programatic, just check the differences in the query parameters and you'll see that `_101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0_cur` is set to the actual page's number (starting from 1).